# Grails Console Error

Tags: grails

When I enter grails console in the gvm, the console loads with several errors. I looked at other answers but it does not refer to the latest version of grails and groovy.

I am running linux mint 17.1 and have grails version 3.0.3, groovy version 2.4.3 and JVM version 1.8.0_45.

Also, below are some of the errors that load:

> Exception in thread "Thread-14"  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
>   No such property: developmentModeActive for class:
>   grails.ui.console.GrailsSwingConsole Possible solutions:
>   developmentModeActive     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
>     at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$_enableDevelopmentModeWatch_closure1.doCall(GrailsApp.groovy:161)
>     at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$_enableDevelopmentModeWatch_closure1.doCall(GrailsApp.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: This doesn't look like a question.  It looks like a bug report.  Please file bug reports at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues.  For this one in particular, I think it has already been fixed.  See my answer below.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fixed in Grails 3.0.4.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9099.